# Shortest path between any origin to any destination through some way stations

Tags: algorithms, graphs, shortest-path, weighted-graphs

How can one find the shortest path between any one of the origins to any one of the destinations through a number of way stations on the way using Dijkstra algorithm?

You can visit those way stations in any order. There will be multiple origins and multiple destinations, but a path from **any** origin to **any** destination will suffice as long as it's the shortest.

Comment: There are two orthogonal concerns here. Can you figure out how to manipulate the graph for multi-source multi-destination without waypoints? How about the other way round?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Without waypoints, it seems fine to use Dijkstra, I initialize the distance for all the source nodes to be 0, and the remaining nodes infinity. Then run the dijkstra on it with a priority queue, whenever I hit one of the destinations, the algorithms stops. Does that sound right? But once I introduce the waypoints, then it doesn't work...

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm misunderstanding the problem, you can't solve this with any simple modification to Dijkstra's because it's NP-complete.

Given an arbitrary graph, call every node a "waystation", then add start/finish nodes that are fully connected. Now running the solver for your problem will solve TSP on the original graph.

Comment: Nothing in the question says anything about polynomial running time.

Comment: @PeterTaylor, buy TSP is *hard* so solve, even exhaustive search is complicated.

Answer (score 1):

You're most of the way there in the comment with the handling of multiple sources and destinations. The simple way to do it is to insert two new vertices: the new source, with a 0-weight edge to each of the multi-sources, and the new destination, with a 0-weight edge from each of the multi-destinations.

---

For the waypoints, I will [quote myself](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/98403/1960):

> This is one of a class of similar problems which can all be handled by deriving a graph $G' = (V', E')$ from the original graph $G = (V, E)$ and then using the standard algorithm on $G'$.
>
> Consider that at any point in your search in $G'$ you need the path information you would have at a corresponding point in the search in $G$ plus the knowledge of ...

here, the knowledge of which waypoints you've already visited. So $G'$ is potentially considerably larger than $G$.

Hint:

> If there are $k$ waypoints, $G'$ will contain $2^k$ copies of $G$, plus some edges connecting them.

Answer (score 0):

You should build a distance matrix with:

- one row respresenting **any origin** and $k$ rows for the $k$ waypoints
- one column representing **any destination** and $k$ columns for the $k$ waypoints.

To fill this matrix, you can run $k+1$ Dijkstra algorithms for each row (time complexity $O(k(|V| + |N|\log |N|))$). For the row any origin, you just start with all origins at distance 0 in your heap.

Then you come to the NP-complete part, you indeed have to solve [Travelling salesman problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) on your distance matrix, starting on the **any origin** row and finishing on the **any destination** column. There are many ways to process it but for small $k$, you can simply use brute force (time complexity $O(!k)$).

So you obtain the shortest distance of the path answering to your problem and the ordered sequence of the waypoints visits. To obtain the path you can run again $k+1$ Dijkstra algorithms to build the path waypoint by waypoint. You can either have stored the path of any value of the distance matrix building it (space complexity $O(|N|k^2)$).